# Bash script to read a file from the command line with list of files

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a bash script that will take in input (a file) from the command line which contains a list of files inside. I then need to open those files inside the file and read it word by word keeping a count of the occurrences of each word in all the files in the list. So far it is printing out the list of files inside the file, but also the file itself. This is what I have so far. I am new to bash scripts so I am not sure how to do this. I appreciate any help. Thanks

```
    #!/bin/bash

    wordArray=()
    countArray=()
    INPUT="$1";

    if [ -f "$INPUT" ]
    then
       find $name -type f
       echo "$name";
    else
       echo "$INPUT is not a file!";
    fi
```

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly be doing what you say it does. Where do you set `$name`?

Comment: why you need the `find` if you have the filenames in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the occurences of all words in all files from the list in one file, you can use:

```
xargs grep -hoP '\b\w+\b' < file_with_list | sort | uniq -c
```

Example:

file list.txt

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

test1.txt

```
hello world
```

test2.txt

```
hello word hello again
```

running:

```
xargs grep -hoP '\b\w+\b' < list.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

prints

```
   1 again
   3 hello
   2 word
```

Caveats:

- the filenames in the `list.txt` can't contain spaces...

Comment: That worked. Thank you! If I wanted to sort it by number of occurrences...what would I need to change?

Comment: Also, it needs to only print valid words to an output file...I know how to check for a valid word, but not within the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

err() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

printwords() {
    echo "Wordcounts in the: $@"
    for i in "${!words[@]}"
    do
        echo "$i => ${words[$i]}"
    done
}

input="$1"
[[ -n $input ]] || err "Usage: $0 filename" || exit 1
[[ -f $input ]] || err "File $input doesn't exists" || exit 2

declare -A words
while read -r file
do
    while read -r word
    do
        let words[$word]++
    done < <(grep -oP '\b\w+\b' "$file")
done < "$input"

printwords "$(cat "$input" | xargs)"
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize -A and is printing out: grep: : No such file or directory

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this instead of find.

```
for name in $INPUT; do echo $name; done
```

this will print all files in your $INPUT file, of course you can do anything else in that loop.

Comment: Please test your script - this will print only the content of the variable `$INPUT` not the content fo the file, what's name is stored in the INPUT...

Comment: Yes, that worked better than using find. Thank you. But how can I open those files in that list to read each word into an array to keep count of the occurrences of each word?

Comment: do cat $name instead of do echo $name

Comment: Ah, I see...yeah, echo just prints the name of the file itself. Thanks