# How would I read in a list of filenames and count all occurrences of each word in all those files? BASH

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

Im trying to write a bash script to read all files in a list of filenames gather every word in all the files, throw them in an array and count them.
The output should be a list of words with the number of occurrences for that word right next to it. 
Im not sure exactly the best way to do this in bash. Thanks for any and all of your help.
The list of filenames is given in a file on the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read f
do
        while read line
        do
                array[i]=$line
                i=$(($i + 1))
        done

done < $1

for e in "${array[@]}"
do
        echo "$e"
done
```

Comment: Strange - yesterday I answered a variant of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25817520/632407). Youre both on the same school?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script to read a file from the command line with list of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816147/bash-script-to-read-a-file-from-the-command-line-with-list-of-files)

Comment: oh wow sorry about that. in all my google searches that one never came up. I wouldnt be surprised if we were in the same class. Thanks !